# How to render textile files in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to view the [readme.textile file from ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/README.textile) in Chrome. But when I open my local file in Chrome it shows all the markup instead of rendering the markup. Is there a way to make chrome render textile files similar to html files? Like an extention of something?

### *I see this:*

[image]

### *But I want to see this:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

GitHub will automatically render Textile files.

Alternatively, you could use the [Textile-JS library](https://github.com/borgar/textile-js). There is a live demo at [this webpage](http://borgar.github.io/textile-js/). Other examples are available on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/textile).

There does not appear to be a Chrome extension currently.

Comment: I actually got the rendered view from GitHub. It seems so weird that Google doesn't do this automatically.